# How can i compress video after being trimmed

Tags: flutter, file, dart, video, compression

i am developing flutter app and trying to compress video after being trimmed  with using `video_trimmer:` but it will not accept the compression

```
 uploadVideo(int data)async { 
await _trimmer.saveTrimmedVideo(startValue: _startValue, endValue: _endValue ) // if i removed this function it will compress perfectly 
    .then((value) async {
  setState(() => file = File(value));
// the path into value is '/data/user/0/com.example.whosaround/app_flutter/Trimmer/WhatsApp_Video_2021-07-01_at_11_trimmed:Jul3,2021-08:27:59.mp4'
});

// compress Video .. will not compress 
  final info = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
    file.path, 
    quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,
    deleteOrigin: false,
    includeAudio: true,
  );
  //refrech file video after compressed
  setState(() => file = File(file.path));
}

  //but will send normally to storage ! 
    if (file == null) return;
    final fileName = basename(file.path);
    final destination = 'files/$fileName';
    task = FirebaseApi.uploadFile( destination,file);
    setState(() {});



}
```

Comment: What is the path in `value`? Is it pointing to a temporary directory?

Comment: this path in value 
'/data/user/0/com.example.whosaround/app_flutter/Trimmer/WhatsApp_Video_2021-07-01_at_11_trimmed:Jul3,2021-08:27:59.mp4'

and this path before the value 
 '/data/user/0/com.example.whosaround/cache/file_picker/WhatsApp Video 2021-07-01 at 11.15.56 PM.mp4'

Comment: please if you have an idea you can edit my code

Comment: I have trying to compress after trimmer using  'VideoCompress' and its not working.
Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  XFile? imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(
        source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (imageFile != null) {
      debugPrint("Selected video => ${imageFile.path}");
      File file = File(imageFile.path);
      var data = await Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return TrimmerView(file);
        }),
      );

      if (data != null) {
        callback.onSuccessTrimVideoFile(data, "video");
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('No video selected.');
    }
```

you can use this method for video thumbnail and Compress

```
 void onSuccessTrimVideoFile(String file, String fileType) {
    Directory appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        String newPath = path.join(appDocPath, '${getRandomString(10)}.mp4');
        File filepath = await File(file).copy(newPath);
    
     final thumbnailFile =await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(filepath.path, quality: 50);
          MediaInfo? mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
            filepath.path,
            quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,
            deleteOrigin: false, // It's false by default
          );
  }
 

String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
      length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
```